# Form submit and HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, javascript, forms, servlets

I'm facing this problem with regards to Forms and Requests. I'm using sencha and javascript to create a webpage that POSTs a form to a java web application which pulls data from a database and formats it before returning a html page to the client.

The problem I'm facing is that for some reason, while the form does get filled(checked using the debugger in chrome), the java program does not recognise the parameter within the form, and instead reads it as null.

I'm following the method of setting the form from an old java program, which works, however it fails for mine. Does anyone know how I can solve this or where I might be doing wrong?

I've included the javascript and java codes where I decide which page to return below.

Javascript handler for function call to submit form:

```
var MenuA = function() {
    simple.getComponent('flag').setValue('MenuA');
    simple.getEl().dom.action = './Soap';
    simple.getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
    simple.submit();}
```

Java code to decide choice of page:

```
if (request.getParameter("flag").matches("MenuA")) {
    choice = 2;
} else if (request.getParameter("flag").matches("MenuB")) {
    choice = 3;}
```

FormPanel Code:

```
var simple = new Ext.form.FormPanel({hidden:true,standardSubmit:true,
items:[
{xtype: 'textfield', hidden: true, name : 'password', label: 'Password', id:'password'}
,{xtype: 'textfield', hidden: true, name : 'user', label: 'user', id:'user'}
,{xtype: 'textfield', hidden: true, name: 'flag', label: 'flag', id: 'flag'}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
request.getParameter("flag").matches("MenuA");
```

method is looking for a form element whose name is "flag".
Since your form may not contain the flag field so it assumes it to be null.
So, to overcome you can add an input field to the form with name "flag" and put put your desired value in it.
I think this should work for you.

Comment: Hi Yadav, thanks for the reply. I actually had a FormPanel in the code already, just forgot to include it above. I just added it into the 1st post. Sorry for forgetting to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Found the problem. I didn't realise the form was not being sent properly. Sorry for the trouble!